# Poetry install on an existing project Error "does not contain any element"

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am using Poetry for the first time.
I have a very simple project. Basically

```
a_project
|
|--test
|    |---test_something.py
|
|-script_to_test.py
```

From a project I do `poetry init` and then `poetry install`

I get the following

```
 poetry install
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.5s)

Writing lock file

Package operations: 7 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing attrs (22.2.0)
  • Installing exceptiongroup (1.1.0)
  • Installing iniconfig (2.0.0)
  • Installing packaging (23.0)
  • Installing pluggy (1.0.0)
  • Installing tomli (2.0.1)
  • Installing pytest (7.2.1)

/home/me/MyStudy/2023/pyenv_practice/dos/a_project/a_project does not contain any element
```

after this I can run `poetry run pytest` without problem but what does that error message mean?

Comment: Please show your `pyproject.toml` as well.

Answer (score 109):

Check if your `pyproject.toml` contains something like:

```
    [tool.poetry]
    packages = [{include = "a_project"}]
```

Removing the line with `packages = [{include = "a_project"}]` helped in my case and should avoid including the root project. See [documentation here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages).

Answer (score 61):

This is probably because Poetry tries to install your project but does not find it (there’s no `a_project` module inside your directory). You can tell it not to install the root project with `--no-root`:

```
poetry install --no-root
```

As of today there is no way to configure this to be the default (see [this issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1132)).

Comment: This answer works very well if you are creating a Docker image for development purposes. I suspect this also should be the "Accepted" answer to the overarching question as well.

Answer (score 1):

My issue got away after pointed correct interpreter in PyCharm. Poetry makes project environment in its own directories and PyCharm didn't link that correct.

I've added new environment in PyCharm and select poetary's just created enviroment in dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a wrong project name in

```
packages = [{include="abc_def_ghi"}]
```

I had used slashes instead of underscores.

Answer (score -1):

create a dir `with_your_package_name` that u find in the file and an empty `__init__.py` in project root

delete the `poetry.lock` and install again

Comment: `with_your_package_name` means `a_project` in this case?