poetry does not find the python version of pyenv
My ubuntu system has pyenv installed. The system python version is 3.8. However I have set pyenv global 3.10.1 and when I do pyenv versions I can clearly see that it is activated. Also doing python --version gives me python 3.10
I have run poetry install in a project, that has as requirements python 3.10 or higher. However poetry tells me
The current activate Python version 3.9.16 is not supported by the project (^3.10)
Trying to find and use a compatible version
Using python3(3.10.1)

and it creates the virtual environment
However in the end it says
/home/user/path/to/project does not contain any element

What could be happening with Poetry and why it recognizes as activated a version that is neither the default or the pyenv one

at request
ls ~/.pyenv/shims/python*
python3
python3.10
python3.11
python3.7
python3.7m
python3.9


run poetry shell, what's the output of which python3?

project does not contain any element is not related, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75397736/poetry-install-on-an-existing-project-error-does-not-contain-any-element

/home/user/.cache.pypoetry/virtualenvs/the-project-PKmkFO-py3.10/bin/python

what about ls ~/.pyenv/shims?

cannot paste that. The output is too large

Read this https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/ I hope it will help you, we are used to work on a local venv in our projects, which makes it easier to follow and maintain

have you ever set pyenv local in the current folder? do you have a file called .python-version somewhere?

I did, but I have tried this in another folder where I didnt and the result is the same

check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062608/how-to-update-alternatives-to-python-3-without-breaking-apt

are you sure you aren't into a virtual env created with python3.9? paste the result of  which python3
